# Updating OSGI config using curl wipes the array values

Tags: curl, osgi, aem, apache-felix

I am trying to update the OSGI configurations on an AEM instance. If I have the following json:

```
{
  "foo": 33,
  "bar": "mystr",
  "baz": ["val1",
          "val2",
          "val3"]
}
```

and I want to update foo to a new value of 51. I tried with the following curl command:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST -d "apply=true" -d "propertylist=foo,bar,baz" -d "foo=51" http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr/com.acme.MyPid
```

Expected result:

```
{
  "foo": 51,
  "bar": "mystr",
  "baz": ["val1",
          "val2",
          "val3"]
}
```

Actual result:

```
{
  "foo": 51,
  "bar": "mystr",
  "baz": []
}
```

Anyone knows anything about why baz array got wiped?

The only way I got it to work is to include every single array item of baz in the curl command. So I needed to add -d "baz=val1" -d "baz=val2" -d baz="val3" to the curl command. In real life (non-foobarbaz life) I have more than one array and my arrays have much more than three items, so I would rather avoid doing so...

I have followed [this link](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-web-console/web-console-restful-api.html) to produce my curl command...

Comment: Have you tried `-d "propertylist=foo" -d "foo=51"`, i.e. only listing the one property you actually want to change in the `propertylist`?

Comment: Yes, I did, but this deleted bar and baz. Both key and value got deleted.